# Hi everyone, I'm trying to create a side slide menu using js but I've encountered this msg. Unexpected 'const'. const navSlide = () => {

Tags: javascript, menu, slide

I'm trying to animate a side slide menu using Js but there seems to be an error in the Js file while validating it. The error says that the const is an unexpected error. I'm a bit lost here.
Validating the css and the html is fine but nothing will happen with the js code.
Basically I'm trying to transfom:translateX(100%) to (0%) adding a .nav-active class to the DOM but with no avail.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.navlinks');

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('.nav-active');
  });
}
navSlide();
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 8vh;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.logo {
  height: 8vh;
}

.logoimg{
  height: 8vh;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-links{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
}

.nav-links li{
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.burger{
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    width: 24px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger{
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active{
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Ryan Ragnini Design and Illustration">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Ryan Ragnini, designer, graphic designer, design, graphic design, webpage, website, logo designer, logo, branding, illustrator, illustration">
    <meta name="author" content="Ryan Ragnini">

    <link type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>Ryan</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <img class="logoimg" src="logo.png" alt="Logo Ryan Ragnini">
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please properly format your question and code.

Comment: What else is in the file? Is this inside a class?

Comment: I changed the format and the code in order to be more understandable. Thank you!